# Latest pidgin installed, but still seeing old version

Tags: linux, package-management

I have installed a new version of pidgin, 2.7.11. In my linux system's application manager this pidgin is the only version selected. But when I open pidgin, the older version (2.7.8) appears.

When i tried to remove it as root it gives the following error:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: Pidgin
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: mirrors.bd-servers.net
 * base: mirrors.bd-servers.net
 * extras: mirrors.bd-servers.net
 * updates: mirrors.bd-servers.net
No package Pidgin available.
  * Maybe you meant: pidgin
No Match for argument: 2.7.8
No Packages marked for removal
```

Why is the older version opening up when I have the latest one installed on my system? Where is the older one even installed?

Comment: which distribution?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your Desktop-Link points to the old version of pidgin.
What kind of Desktop Manager are you using? Depending on your Desktop Manager you can change that link (Desktop Icon --to--> binary).

To find out the location of the "default" pidgin use an console-command

```
type pidgin
```

...should return something like "pidgin is /usr/bin/pidgin"

What version of pidgin starts when you run the binary returned by `type pidgin`?

What Linux distribution/package manager are you using? Depending on the package manager there are different command-line tools to get the information which pidgin package is installed.

Look at your error-log.
Did you recognize the following lines?

```
No package Pidgin available.
  * Maybe you meant: pidgin
```

Remember, that commands in Linux are case sensitive.